# How to find out fragmented indexes and defragment them in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, fragmentation, defragmentation

I've found how we can solve this problem in SQL Server [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11775270/10092297) - but how can i do it in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Normally you don't have to worry about that at all.

However, if there has been a mass delete or update, or the sustained change rate was so high that autovacuum couldn't keep up, you may end up with a badly bloated index.

The tool to determine that id the `pgstattuple` extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgstattuple;
```

Then you can examine index bloat like this:

```
SELECT * FROM pgstatindex('spatial_ref_sys_pkey');

-[ RECORD 1 ]------+-------
version            | 2
tree_level         | 1
index_size         | 196608
root_block_no      | 3
internal_pages     | 1
leaf_pages         | 22
empty_pages        | 0
deleted_pages      | 0
avg_leaf_density   | 64.48
leaf_fragmentation | 13.64
```

This index is in excellent shape (never used): It has only 14% bloat.

Mind that indexes are by default created with a `fillfactor` of 90, that is, index blocks are not filled to more than 90% by `INSERT`.

It is hard to say when an index is bloated, but if `leaf_fragmentation` exceeds 50-60, it's not so pretty.

To reorganize an index, use `REINDEX`.

Comment: Be cautious about using REINDEX on  big indexes as write locks are obtained on the parent table.
One strategy to achieve the same result on a live site is to build an index concurrently on the same table and columns but with a different name, and then dropping the original index and renaming the new one. This procedure, while much longer, won’t require any long running locks on the live tables.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-indexes#managing-and-maintaining-indexes

Comment: @RohitTaneja PostgreSQL v12 has `REINDEX CONCURRENTLY` which makes that easier.

Answer (score 4):

With PostgreSQL index defragmentation should generally be handled automatically by the [Autovacuum daemon](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html). If you don't use the autovacuum daemon, or if it isn't able to keep up, you can always [reindex problematic indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reindex.html).

Determining which indexes may be badly fragmented isn't particularly straight forward and it's discussed at length in [this blog post](https://pgeoghegan.blogspot.com/2017/07/postgresql-index-bloat-microscope.html) and [in this PostgreSQL wiki article](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index_Maintenance).